# Maximum size of Android Clipboard

Tags: android, clipboard

Is there a maximum size of Android Clipboard?

On Nexus 5, I was trying to copy Facebook app's open source software license which is extremely long, but failed. Selecting all was succeeded, but I couldn't copy or share it.

Comment: Size may be depends based on the RAM, ROM. So it will be vary on different devices. Nexus 5 has 2GB RAM. I believe you are not able to copy the text properly.

Comment: @Kedarnath Thanks for your comment. Do you know how to calculate the size based on the RAM and ROM? How come 2GB RAM is not enough? I mean most high-end phones have 2GB RAM..

Comment: me too wants to know this, Similar issues are still unanswered!

Answer (score 0):

There is an App for Android called 'VT View Source' you can grab and save the html source of a html page with. But it doesn't show javascript loaded or autogenerated text.
With a bit luck you can grab the text with it or at least find a direct link to the text source with it.