# Is there any characters/bytes limit in the Android clipboard? [Android development]

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, clipboard

Good night everyone,

Lately, I have been learning about the Android clipboard. I was trying to do some interesting stuff when I discovered that I couldn't copy more than 2^18 (262.144) characters at once. I have been researching here in stackoverflow and I have found that there is a limit, but this is 1/16 of the ram memory of the phone. In my case, I have tried to run the app in my 512mb ram memory phone, so I should be able to storage about 32mb, much more of those 262.144 bytes I currently can.

First of all, I want to specify that I copy the text from the code (Android studio) directly to the clipboard, not from the device. What I do to copy those characters in the clipboard is to use a for to quickly and efficiently increment the caracters of the String I will pass a parametre to the ClipData, and then to the clipboard. Then, I pass it to the clipdata and afterwards, to the clipboard. The thing is that when I run the app, when the String I want to copy is larger than 262.144 characters, it simply doesn't copy anything (when I want to paste it, it pastes what I had before in the clipboard). It perfectly works with an amount of characters shorter than those I've said. It's really strange.

Can anybody help me, please?

Thank you very much, and forgive me for my poor English.

Comment: I have never heard of your "1/16 of the ram" limit. There is a 1MB limit on most IPC operations, and so I would not be surprised if there is a limit around there. Certainly, there could be a lower limit like you are experiencing. That being said, putting 256KB on the clipboard of a mobile device seems rather excessive.

Comment: Well, I found it on this post, but I am not really sure if it's true.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041031/maximum-size-of-android-clipboard
Then, perhaps it's what you say, thanks.